# PayPal chained payments with variable recipients (from non-US business account)

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a hard time finding clear answers to what's involved in implementing following case of chained payments using PayPal...

We are based in New Zealand, offering following types of accounts:
https://www.paypal.com/nz/webapps/mpp/compare-business-products
Currently, we have a Business Express Checkout account.

Our browser app allows users to set up product configurators.  The configurators are then used by other users (consumers), to purchase configured products.

A. **Simple payment case**:
When consumers pay for the configured product, we are the primary recipient, and pass on the payment to the owner of the configurator, minus our revenue share %.

B. **Complex Payment case**:
Same as A, but multiple secondary recipients.  We can't use parallel payments, because the multiple recipients need to be obfuscated.

For each case:

1. If not chained payments, what is the best fit PayPal option?  Which API, if applicable?
2. Does the Express Checkout account support the required API?  If not, which account type, available in New Zealand, does?
3. Which of the parties requires approval from PayPal? What type of approval? How long does the approval process take, and what affects its success?
4. Any other considerations when moving from the sandbox to the live setup?
5. What's the cost of the solution?

We'd obviously favour solutions that require minimal approval hassle, as we will be dealing with many configurators.

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems like Adaptive Chained Payment is your best option.
2. Express Checkout support parallel payment but Express Checkout does not support chained payment.
3. You need a apply for an APP id if you're using Adaptive Payment. I could not answer how long it will took for them to approve.
4. Everything is the same when you're moving in Live. Just make sure your App has been approved, and the endpoint is change to Live.
5. The only cost is the PayPal fee's that PayPal collect for each transaction you made.